# start an activity without show it

Tags: android, background, back-button, android-context, start-activity

I was trying to start activity from a service without showing it to the user, keep it work in background, I was searching a lot about that, and I found two ways to do that

1. by starting the activity then start the home main screen like this :

   ```
   // this is for lunch the app
   Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.some");

   // this is for going back
   Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
   startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
   startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

   // lets do it !
   startActivity(LaunchIntent);
   startActivity(startMain);
   ```

2. by putting a going back function in the activity itself, like this :

   ```
   context.getActivity().moveTaskToBack(true);
   ```

BUT, in these two ways I have problems 
in the first one, if the user was on another app, this operation will close his app and get him to home , more than that, some times the my activity not started but just be in the back without working i.e. if there was a song it isn't played 
in second one, when the my activity started a black screen will appear for a second before it back to the home or previous user app

**So , simply , this is what I want :
I want a behaviour equal to : the user open my app then he press back button, but without show that the app started unless he see the background apps**

how to do that ?

Comment: From the official Activity documentation: `An activity is a single, focused thing that the user can do. [...]` The only problem I see here seems to be your overall design, no offense. You obviously don't need to use an `Activity`, or you're using it badly.

Comment: I have to do that to achieve something , I'am flash AS3 developer and I use air in the first place , I know that service is much better to do such things , but I need to open my air app in the background to achieve  the thing I want

Comment: I'm sorry I don't see it. You only need an Activity for user interactions or at least it's focus. No matter what is "the thing" you want, you should achieve that without an Activity. Or your design is kinda bad IMHO.

Comment: I have seen a lot of questions about the same topic for multiple reasons , and these two ways is from these questions , their is a lot of reason to do that

Comment: any way , thanks for your comment , looking for technical comment

Comment: Fair enough. There is no "resume" notion on the `Application` object, so I guess you should have a custom `Activity` class and detect your special case in `onCreate()` for example, then call a `finish()`. Do you have the hand on the `Intent` that will start your Activity? If yes (as you should, since your `Service` seems to be doing the work), you could add an extra and detect that event this way... Just some thoughts.

Answer (score -1):

For that, you can use an android Service.
See docs - http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: I know about services , but I want to use the activity itself , I'am launching the activity from service in the first place

Comment: I think that is no possible to do without a Service. Every time an application goes to background, the system can kill them when need memory, so you loose the control. Sorry